# How to scrape a hidden table with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

It's about scraping a hidden table with `beautifulsoup`.

As you can see in [this website](https://www.ticketmaster.fr/fr/manifestation/holiday-on-ice-billet/idmanif/446304), there is a button "choisissez votre séance" and when we click on it a table will be shown.

When I click on inspect the table element i can see the tag that contains attributes like price. However, when I view the website's source code, I can't find this information.

There is something in the code of the table 'display : none' which I think affects this, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: I do not see any button with that text. Instead, I see a button with this text _Choisissez vos places sur le plan_

Comment: BS can get element even if it has `display:none` but it can't get item if it is loaded by JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear the page is using AJAX and loading the data for pricing in the background. Using Chrome I pressed F12 and had a look under the network tab. When I clicked the "choisissez votre séance" button I noticed a POST to this address:

'https://www.ticketmaster.fr/fr/manifestation/holiday-on-ice-billet/idmanif/446304'

This is great news for you as you do not need to scrape the HTML data, you simply need to provide the ID (in page source) to the API.

In the below code I am

1. Requesting the initial page
2. Collecting the cookie
3. Posting the ID (data) and the cookie we collected
4. Returning the JSON data you require to further process (variable J)

Hope the below helps out!

Cheers,
Adam

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'}
s = requests.session()

initial_page_request = s.get('https://www.ticketmaster.fr/fr/manifestation/holiday-on-ice-billet/idmanif/446304',headers=h)

soup = BeautifulSoup(initial_page_request.text,'html.parser')
idseanc = soup.find("select",{"id":"sessionsSelect"})("option")[0]['value'].split("_")[1]

cookies = initial_page_request.cookies.get_dict()

headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://www.ticketmaster.fr',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'https://www.ticketmaster.fr/fr/manifestation/holiday-on-ice-billet/idmanif/446304',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

data = {'idseanc':str(idseanc)}

response = s.post('https://www.ticketmaster.fr/planPlacement/FindPrices/connected/false/idseance/2870471', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)

j = response.json()
```

Comment: please how do you find this information ? because i need to adapt it to scrap a lot of pages and this id is for a specific page                                                                        data = {'idseanc':'2870471'}

response = s.post('https://www.ticketmaster.fr/planPlacement/FindPrices/connected/false/idseance/2870471', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)                                                       thank you

Comment: Also i try to scrap with findAll the idseanc from the web source but i can't. Python return a list which is empty [ ] .                          thank

Comment: I have updated the code to obtain the ID from the page you are currently visiting.

Comment: Ok thank you, i have a problem with some article, the script you propose can't find the id. for example this one :                                                       https://www.ticketmaster.fr/fr/pack/package-little-mix-billet/idpack/1807                                                                                     The error is 'NoneType' object is not callable.                                                          I think, maybe, the website is blocking my scraping ?

Comment: The page you provided is completely different to the page in your initial question. Also, Ticketmaster is known to have very good anti-scraping technology. Best of luck!

Comment: Do you think ticketmaster is blocking me ?, i try with the a website with the same structure but have NoneType Object https://www.ticketmaster.fr/fr/manifestation/jo-dw-t-fil-billet/idmanif/461188

Comment: It is highly likely my friend, change up your IP and see if that helps.